# Spring Security UserMap is deprecated, how to use plain map?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, spring-security

Spring Security 3.0.5 is throwing the following warning in Eclipse:

`Class 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.memory.UserMap' is marked deprecated`

for the following configuration:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="john" password="john"
                authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <security:user name="admin" password="admin"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="system" password="system"
                authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="guest" password="guest"
                authorities="ROLE_GUEST" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

The [Javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/memory/UserMap.html) say, just use a plain map instead.  But I'm not sure what they mean by that and where does the plain map go?  I'm a bit thrown off by the "help" the security namespace is providing...

Comment: Can you show us what `schemaLocation` you provided in your spring-security xml config (at the top of the file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's already fixed in 3.1, since `UserMap` was used in `InMemoryDaoImpl` class, which was superseded by [`InMemoryUserDetailsManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/InMemoryUserDetailsManager.html) [in this commit](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/commit/f5859fabcf53857389cdd2dd4d31c9be6b7c4500#core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/provisioning/InMemoryUserDetailsManager.java) (included in 3.1).

If you can upgrade - do it, if not - just ignore the warning (it's STS complaining about Spring Security internals which are working properly after all).

Comment: Didn't occur to me than an upgrade would resolve it...or that it was a Spring problem.  But thinking about it, I guess it would HAVE to be a Spring problem because it's their namespace shortcut that's causing the warning.  In any event, upgrading to 3.1.2 fixed it.  Thanks.